# "Method not allowed" returned to ajax call upon session expiry

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, session

I have a table where i show list of categories and delete button for each category on each row. Delete action works via ajax call using below route:

```
Route::delete('category/delete/{id}','CategoriesController@destroy')->name('category.delete');
```

It works fine. But then i left the page open and came back after some time while the page was still open. Now when i tried to delete a category i am getting **Method not allowed** error from my controller. I think it has something to do with the session being expired.

My questions are:
 
1. why this is happening
2. How do i handle this ON SERVER SIDE so that in cases when the session has expired and the user tries to access a protected route(via ajax), the server detect the session expiry and sends a particular response to the ajax call or  redirects the user to the login page.

My ajax call expects a json type in return from the server.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Laravel? Are you using the `api` routing? if so, session's not passed through it and you need to manually check for it or add a middelware.

Comment: If your session is expired then it will either redirect to login (302) or give and 401 response code. You should check the response code of your request.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai: No i am not using api routing.

Comment: @GopalKildoliya: In the network tab i can see the status code for this request is  **302 Found** but in the location field tells i am being redirected to this page again(http://blog.dev/admin/category/all) and not the login page. I guess that is why i am getting status code **405 Method not allowed** as this is a GET route but being redirected here as DELETE route.

Answer (score 1):

When the session expires, any route that needs authentication redirects to the /login endpoint, and since that is only `get&post` the `delete` fails.

Possible solutions:

- increase the session duration (default is 120 minutes)
- add a jquery interceptor to detect 401's and `window.location.reload()` the browser window to make the user go to the login page himself
- put a timer in the script that 'pings' the server every ~5/10 minutes or so, therefore bumping the session

Comment: Did you mean **405**? Cause i am getting **405** and not **401**. Also is there any server side solution like a middleware that checks for session validation of the incoming request and redirects to login page. I guess the Auth middleware should do that already as my routes are protected by Auth middleware. But it is not doing so!!

Comment: Only the ajax hits the auth check and gets redirected to login, not the browser itself, and you could/shout check for 405 & 401 for maximum coverage in your case